# Enabling and disabling keyboard input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I want to disable keyboard input. However I still want to postback the form as part of collection so adding the 'disabled' attribute isnt the solution for me.

I have added this code to make the input readonly:

```
 //code to not allow any changes to be made to input field
        $(".customreadonly").keydown(function () {
            return false;
        });
```

And then I set this class like this:

```
  $("#StartRRP").addClass('customreadonly');
```

However when I remove the class like this:

```
$("#StartRRP").removeClass('customreadonly');
```

The input still wont allow keyboard input. This seems to be trivial, what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In addition to the `disabled` attribute, there's also the `readonly` attribute. A field can have `readonly` set and it will still be submitted.

Comment: @Pointy you are right. But I also need unobtrusive validation to work. Readonly fields are ignored by this. For most uses, using readonly would be the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you attach the event directly to the jQuery object, it remains even after the initial selector to it is no longer valid(ie, class removed).

Either explicitly unbind

```
$("#StartRRP").removeClass('customreadonly');
$("#StartRRP").unbind('keydown');
```

or change your approach to use delegation

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".customreadonly", function () {
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a very short and well explained answer. Thank you again for such a swift response.